# disable crawling subdomain google crawler

Tags: web-crawler, google-crawlers

i would like to know how i can disallow google the crawling of my subdomains ?

i made a pic of my webspace folder. the awesom media folder is the folder where the main site www.awesom-media.de is.[folders](http://de.tinypic.com/r/fzaro7/8)

the other once are subdomains. what i whant is that google should not crawl this one but i dont know how .

i dont have a robot.txt in the awesom media folder but as u can see in the / part. and the content of the robot.txt is `User-agent: *
Disallow:`

and thats it.

how can i tell google not to crawl the subdomains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case all your subdomains directly route to the specific folders (e.g. something like *automagazin.awesom-media.de* uses the folder `auto-magazin`), just place a robots.txt with

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

in all your folders for the subdomains you want to disallow for Google. I guess these are `auto-magazin` and `future-magazin` (and maybe more).

Currently you put it into the root folder, which Google probably cannot see at all. Just try to load *[subdomain].awesom-media.de/robots.txt* and see if it loads a robot.txt or not.

Comment: ah sorry my mistake. automagazin | mylife| concierg and future-magazin are no subdomains. that are normal domains, wich is part of my webspace.

the subdomains are the folders schmidt; HMA, limo, backend,

Comment: now i put into all subdomain folders a robot.txt with the line that u post.

schimdt.awesom-media.de/robot.txt is also working. is that so correct ?

Comment: Mea culpa, of course it has to be `Disallow: /`. I corrected my posting. Otherwise you will **allow** everything for Google.